# Change nicescroll hand cursor to default cursor

Tags: javascript, nicescroll

Am using nicescroll in my code. Is there any way to change the nicescroll hand cursor to default arrow cursor?

Answer (score 1):

Set the [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor) property with the appropriate selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Nicescroll uses grabbing cursor by default. You can use the **grabcursorenabled** parameter to remove this hand/grab cursor.

```
$(yourElement).niceScroll({
    grabcursorenabled: false,
   ..// other parameters
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

in `jquery.nicescroll.js` file, find `function detectCursorGrab()` (in v.3.4.0 is in the line:186)

There you have the function that changes the cursor.

Play with that function to fix your needs.

Good luck

BTW, the `default` arrow in CSS is: `#id{cursor:default}`